# How attach mail template in .NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asp.net-core

I am trying to attach the mail template in Mail Kit I am using .NET Core
here is my code

```
  //From Address    
            string FromAddress = "info@gorollo.com";
            string FromAdressTitle = "Gorollo";
            //To Address    
            string ToAddress = email;
            string Subject = subject;
            string BodyContent = message;
            var body = new BodyBuilder();
            var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
            mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress
                                    (FromAdressTitle,
                                     FromAddress
                                     ));
            mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress
                                     (
                                     ToAddress
                                     ));
            mimeMessage.Subject = Subject;
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Connect("smtp.mailgun.org", 587, false);
                client.Authenticate(
                    "info@gorollo.com",
                    "password"
                    );
                await client.SendAsync(mimeMessage);
                await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
            }
```

i saw many examples but not able to find the exact solution
so please anyone help me to sort out the problem 
I have to attach Signup template in my mail here.

Comment: What do you mean by attaching a mail template? Do you just want to add some text or HTML to the mail message?

Comment: i have to send mail with mail template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost here. You can use the `BodyBuilder` to add text or HTML to the body. Either use the `TextBody` or `HtmlBody` property to set text or HTML respectively. Use the `ToMessageBody()` method to create a `MimeEntity` instance which you can use as the mail body.

Example:

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>";
message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
```

Comment: yes but i want to attach HTML template with this mail

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 you can add the HTML content of the template in the `bodyBuilder.HtmlBody` property.

Comment: sir can you please show that how to add template in body  i would be very thankful to you.
my HTML page is  SignupConformation.HTML file

Comment: You will have to read the HTML file from your local file systeminto a string, by using `File.ReadAllText()` for example.

Comment: can you please show me in a code  that how can i able to read it sir